# What does the @ in front of a parameter name do?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio

What does the `@` sign does when inserted in front of parameters SQL query?

for example:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [User] values (@Forename, @Surname, @Username, @Password)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Forename", txtForename.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUsername.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Note: the @ is not needed for the parameter name, only the sql statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to what other people have said here, the `@` character doesn't do anything per se. You can either add the parameter with

```
.AddWithValue("ParaName",value);
```

or

```
.AddWithValue("@ParaName",value);
```

And they both will be matched to a paramater named `@ParamName` on the DB side. So it is NOT required.

Having said that, it's a pretty standard practice to always use the `@` in front of the parameter because that's exactly how it will be named in the database side.

Comment: yeah i had thought the same when i was programming, but i was told by someone that leaving the parameter without the @ would mean my code is more vulnerable to an SQL injection, is this true or...

Comment: @bandaa not at all, at least not in this context! You are using parameters and they are not prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @bandaa: Sql Injection threat is *`mostly`* about non parameterised queries. Ex: `"select col1 from table1 where x = '" + txtName.Text + "'"`. Here, `txtName.Text` can be anything and it could break the query if it has `'` in it as well...

Comment: Oracle uses the : and fails if you add the : to the parameter name.

Answer (score 7):

That's just what indicates that it *is* a parameter name in the query - as opposed to trying to use a field from the column.

It's not clear whether it's strictly needed when constructing the `SqlParameter` object, but I think it makes sense to be consistent :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing magical - It's just the syntax SQL uses to denote parameters and local variables.  It's not the same as the C# `@` character that tells the compiler not to process escape-sequences in string literals:

```
string stringWithSlashes = @"Use '\n' to add a new line";
```

or that lets you use reserved words as variable names:

```
string @class = "Geometry";
```

Answer (score 0):

`@` says it is a input/output parameter whose value can be passed from outside the script.

Comment: Could be an output parameter as well :)

Answer (score 0):

`@` sign means on [`SqlParameterCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wce29x9.aspx) *the name of the parameter*. Using field from the column.

```
Parameters

parameterName
Type: System.String

The name of the parameter.
```

Answer (score 0):

The @ in that case is a SQL Server construct. Parameters to SQL Server queries are specified with the @ symbol since T-SQL (SQL Server programming language) uses the @ symbol for variables.